# Social sign in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-signin

For a flutter app, I need to develop some API using `Django rest-framework`. For the authentication what I have done so far, using simple token auth. When a new user sign-up and then verify his email, I generate a token and that token is then used to send requests. For logout, the token that is generated before needs to be deleted from the front end and redirected to the login page. If the user wants to log in again, the user needs to provide the email and the password. If the credentials are correct, the token is sent again.

Now I have to implement `Google sign-in`. I am confused about the workflow. Can anyone guide me on how to do this same thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google login in django rest framework + allauth + rest-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252301/google-login-in-django-rest-framework-allauth-rest-auth)